# Proving an identity of the Lebesgue integral of a sublinear operator

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $T$ be a sublinear operator. Suppose that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $A$ is a set of finite Lebesgue measure. Then I want to prove that for all $0<p<1$, we have $$\int_{A}|T(f)(x)|^{p}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}p\alpha^{p-1}|\{x\in A:|T(f)(x)|>\alpha\}|d\alpha$$

I'm not sure, but I think that we can write something similar to $$\int_{A} f d\mu=\int\frac{1}{\lambda}\mu\{x\in A:f(x)>\lambda\}d\lambda$$

Otherwise I'm not sure I have the tools to prove this identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this has nothing whatever to do with $T$; the identity you want is just $$\int_{A}f(x)^{p}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}p\alpha^{p-1}|\{x\in A:f(x)>\alpha\}|d\alpha\quad (f\ge0).$$

And that's a perfectly standard thing. You must have seen very similar things or you wouldn't be thinking of this - given that, it's hard to see where the problem is; the proof you've seen works just fine. Write
$$f(x)^p=\int_0^{f(x)}p\alpha^{p-1}\,d\alpha.$$Insert that on the left hand side and use Fubini (or rather Tonelli).

(The second displayed equation in your post is wrong; the $1/\lambda$ shouldn't be there.)

Comment: I don't see immediately how it follows from Tonelli that $$\int_{A}\int_{0}^{f(x)}p\alpha^{p-1}d\alpha=\int_{0}^{\infty}p\alpha^{p-1}|\{x\in A: f(x)>\alpha\}| d\alpha$$

Comment: Well, what _do_ you get when you apply Tonelli to the iterated integral?

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}\int_{A}\int_{0}^{f(x)}p\alpha^{p-1}d\alpha dx&=\int_{0}^{f(x)}\int_{A}p\alpha^{p-1}dx d\alpha \\ &=\int_{0}^{f(x)}p\alpha^{p-1}\{x\in A\}d\alpha \\ &=\cdots \end{aligned}$$

Comment: You're "changing the limits" wrong. $\int_A \int_0^{f(x)} dadx$ does not become $\int_0^{f(x)}\int_A dxda$. Find a calculus book, study the examples and exercises on things like changing $\int_0^1\int_0^x dydx$ to $dxdy$...